# Using mmap data with objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, mmap

How does one use mmapped data with objects?

e.g. A UIImage.

If I know the offset and the number of bytes, and I can retrieve it, how is this used with objects?

I am a little confused on how to pass the data to an object, how does the object only use the exact number of bytes?

I currently fetch mmapped data byte by byte and write it to a file, this creates an image, but I am not sure on how to do this with an object.

Obviously there is no need to alloc the object as the data is available, but how is it passed to and managed by the object internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, the only way to allocate a Cocoa object is with `+alloc`.  I don't think you can realistically use mmapped memory to persist objects.

However, you can use it to retrieve the image data for a UIImage.

```
NSData* theData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy: pointerToMMappedData 
                                       length: dataLength  
                                 freeWhenDone: NO];
UIImage* anImage = [UIImage imageWithData: theData];
```

Comment: That last part was exactly what I was looking for thanks. So once the data is assigned to the NSData object, any other object can be setup using this data?

Comment: @Helium3: `theData` object is initialised so that it doesn't own the bytes it points to.  You can set up any other object using the same bytes, but it would be a bad idea to try to change them or to unmap the memory while the data object still exists.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it will be mapped. What if the data in virtual memory is compressed and the objects needs to have the decompressed data? There are zlib functions for decompression on the fly, but where will this data be kept? If there are 50 objects using their own decompressed data segments, will these all be on the stack?

Comment: @Helium3: As long as the data looks the same as image data in a file, UIImage will cope.